# LoadRunner Correlation 'Ord' random issue

Tags: performance-testing, correlation, loadrunner

I am able to capture the response using `ord=All` in `web_reg_save_param`.

case 1,
Input:12345
Response:["18/3/2017","20/2/2017","20/2/2016"].

case 2,
Input:98451
Response:["12/1/2017","01/1/2016"]

`web_reg_save_param("date","LB=\"","RB=\"","ORD=ALL","LAST);`
`
Captured Values are:

`date_1:18/3/2017`

`date_2:,`

`date_3:20/2/2017`

`date_4:,`

`date_5:20/2/2016`

**Here is the task:**

1) I need to fetch random date each time.

2) Date may vary depending upon the input(In case 1, 3 dates and case 2, 2 dates).

I have tried:

1) Correlating and using `lr_paramarr_random()` function- failed, it will fetch ',' at some point.

2) using for loop and if statement to find out odd/even position.

Answer (score 2):

Using **web_reg_save_param()** function like you did will, of course, fetch a comma(',') since it is situated between two quote symbols(' " ').

You can use **web_reg_save_param_regexp()** function with the following regular expression:

```
"(\d{2}\/\d\/\d{4})"
```

Set the parameters: "Ordinal=All", "Group=1".

This function will extract the dates and store them into an array.

This time **lr_paramarr_random()** should return correct results because now your array contains nothing but dates.